# Plone 4: Accessing content via a custom ID in path

Tags: url, plone, directory

Heya I'm fairly new to Plone development. And I'm sitting with a problem.

I have a folder in Plone that contains products.

```
http://plonesite/products
```

What I would like to do, is to access the products directly when a call like this is made.

```
http://plonesite/products/4244-24
```

Preferably I want to mark the folder with a custom interface IE. *IProductFolder*. So whenever a user access:

```
http://plonesite/products
```

a script needs to be called and check whether there is a product number in the URL and perform a catalog search and redirect to the product. If the search doesn't return any results or the argument after **/products/** is invalid it just continues to render the page.

I just don't know how to do this kind of setup. I've looked into adapters but they won't even work. Can anyone help me with a quick example?

Comment: But if your product entity is a Plone content, why don't simply rename it's id to "4244-24"?

Comment: All the products are imported from another source, and all the products doesn't have product ID. Otherwise I would of course do that.

Comment: Would something like `products/nr/4244-24` be acceptable? Views (and I guess Scripts, too) can access path information, so you could have a view named `nr`.

Comment: Sadly no :(
The whole problem is that there are old links in circulation to specific products. What I would like to do is to support the old links. And also be able to support this on serveral folders (running lingua plone), hence the interface trigger.

Comment: You could look at how `plone.app.blob`'s Image type provides access to `image_thumb` et al. However, that might not work with a marker interface since you need to override a traverse method.

Comment: I assume you've found the possibilities in [the plone docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/serving/traversing.html#id26)?

Comment: Plone can handle old links with [`plone.app.redirector`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.redirector). Maybe this package can help you to figure out a alternative solution.

Comment: You need to make your products content class provide or be adaptable to IPublishTraverse, and your publishTraverse(name) method should return proxy objects of some sort that are publishable by Zope.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions I will look into the options tomorrow and return.

Comment: I had to go by another solution, I had to reimport all the items again and force name them accordingly to their product numbers also for other reasons. Thanks for all tips!

Answer (score 1):

[collective.routes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.routes/1.1a2) allows you to create URLs based on catalog data. Exactly what you're after. Don't be scared by the alpha status; the package works as documented.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll save it for the future